# Can I buy an Apple SIM card if I’m not a resident of the country where it's sold?

Tags: ipad, cellular-data, sim, apple-store

Can [Apple SIM](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203099) cards be freely purchased, or are they tied to having an address in one of the thirteen countries where they are sold? I noticed an article on Mac Rumors that headlines [“Truphone's Apple SIM Data Plans for iPad Will Be Available to Buy in Over 30 Countries Later This Year”](https://www.macrumors.com/2017/10/06/truphone-apple-sim-ipad-data-plans-expanding/). As I understand, data plans for an Apple SIM card can be purchased in other countries besides the 13 where Apple sells the cards. It sounds like it might be useful to have a card around, can I buy one when visiting one of the 13 countries? How much does Apple charge for the card?

[Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203099) lists the countries where an Apple SIM card can be bought:

> If your iPad didn't come with an Apple SIM card, you can buy an Apple SIM kit at an Apple Retail Store in the United States, the United Kingdom, Australia, Canada, France, Germany, Italy, Japan, Netherlands, Spain, Sweden, Switzerland, or Turkey.

Comment: I'm not sure that *buying it* would be the issue - running it on an unrecognised phone provider's network would probably be the blocker. If it did work, maybe by getting a contract from the source country, you might run up some high international charges, as it would be constantly in roaming mode.

Comment: I may have misunderstood how Apple SIM cards work. Don't these allow you to freely switch between providers? According to the Mac Rumors article, the Truphone plans are, for example, already available for purchase in Poland, but not in Germany. Apple SIM cards are sold in Germany but not in Poland. I thought that a Polish citizen could hop over to Germany to buy a card, and buy a Truphone plan at home (right from the iPad). I thought the only problem with this scenario might be that buying the card might require registration. Did I misunderstand and might there be other issues?

Comment: tbh, I don't know - I'd ask Truphone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can<sup>1</sup>.

I can confirm that you are able to get an Apple SIM, regardless of the status of residence in the country you are buying it in. Buying an Apple SIM does not require registration.

In Canada, it cost CA$5.00 for one.

<sup>1</sup>Can’t find a source, but I tried it out.